# Next.js - new Date() constructor throwing console errors

Tags: reactjs, date, next.js

I'm trying to use new Date() constructor in Next.js react component. But its throwing below console errors on production.

This is how I'm using the date constructor.

`date: "2022-06-21T18:30:00.000Z"`

`{new Date(date).toLocaleDateString("en-US")}`

```
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #425; - https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=425
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #418; - https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=418
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #423; - https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=423
```

Any idea why its happening. Helps would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [Hydration errors - Text content does not match server-rendered HTML](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/38263). I guess this post is what you want to find. The errors seem to be produced mostly by the **Time and randomness**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per @bcjohn's comment I have figured out that hydration errors can be fixed by formatting the date in `useEffect` instead of directly adding it in `jsx`.

Here's the custom hook that I written for formatted date.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useFormattedDate = (date) => {
  const [formattedDate, setFormattedDate] = useState(null);

  useEffect(
    () => setFormattedDate(new Date(date).toLocaleDateString("en-US")),
    []
  );

  return formattedDate;
};

export default useFormattedDate;
```

Sample usage

```
const date = useFormattedDate(obj.date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your “date” a variable on its own or is it a property of an object. If it is a variable, you should do “date = “ and not “date:” , if it is a property of an object, you should do “new Date(object.date)” . Replace object with the name of your object

Comment: Thanks @Ani. Its property of an object. But this is not I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

To fix hydration warnings, see the docs. Using **useEffect** is one option, which might not be viable in all cases.

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

You can also **disable** SSR on a component level OR
**surpress** the warning on the element.

e.g.

```
<td className="font-bold" suppressHydrationWarning>{`${dateTime.toLocaleTimeString()}`}</td>
```