# Uncaught Error: Minified React error #425

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, deployment, next.js

When moving my application to production, these errors appeared, and I have no idea what it could be.

[image: console devTools. Error message.]

I'm using:

```
    // package.json
    "dependencies": {
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^1.35.6",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.2",
    "duration-fns": "^3.0.1",
    "next": "^12.2.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.34.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8"
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Next.js - new Date() constructor throwing console errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73005663/next-js-new-date-constructor-throwing-console-errors)?

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/37489

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73602690/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

I notice `date-fns` in your dependencies. I suspect you're creating a new date inside your render.

Any *impure* values (like the current date) computed and used on initial render in your component will produce a content mismatch:

`Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.`

## Solution

The solution is to create your date(s) inside `useEffect`. Now only the client computes the new date and updates the DOM.

An example might be changing this:

```js
export default function App() {
  return <div>{format(new Date(), "MM.dd.yyyy")}</div>;
}
```

To this:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setDate(format(new Date(), "MM.dd.yyyy"));
  }, []);

  return <div>{date}</div>;
}
```

Now the impure value is computed only after mount on the client and the mismatch cited in the hydration error will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what the issue is from only this, I would guess you use a custom bundling solution / manual setup. Do you think you could be persuaded to move to something like Create React App?

Comment: i'm using NextJS and this error only happens in the host build. I tried it in Vercel and Netlify and the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The issue I've been through

```
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #425;
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #423;
```

error)

```
<style>
```

resolve)

```
<style jsx>
```

nextjs styled-jsx link)

https://nextjs.org/blog/styling-next-with-styled-jsx

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

All your variables that depend on or collect values from the browser, need to be placed in a useEffect.

An example that causes this error and it happened to me:

```
const device = 'other';
if (
      typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
      typeof window.navigator !== 'undefined'
    ) {
      const ua = navigator.userAgent;

      if (/android/i.test(ua)) {
        device = 'android';
      }
    }
```

To solve it, I just put this condition inside the useEffect, so the code doesn't differ from what the browser is expecting:

```
  const [device, setDevice] = useState('other');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (
      typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
      typeof window.navigator !== 'undefined'
    ) {
      const ua = navigator.userAgent;

      if (/android/i.test(ua)) {
        setDevice('android');
      }
    }
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a cookie consent library causing this. Check that also if you are using one.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to set up env variables in Vercel settings. Check that if you're using Vercel.