# Minified React error #425 - Because of timezone format

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel

Trying to solve this weird problem which only occurs on Vercel.

The error I am getting:

```
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #425; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=425 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
```

Because of this line:

```
const result = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone.replace(/^.*\//, "")
```

This issue doesn't happen on local machine, development or production mode. Only when deployed to Vercel.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the vercel server being in another time zone than your local machine. That's also the reason why you do not encounter the error locally because your local server is not in another time zone.

Since the date on the vercel server is not the same as on your client, the vercel server assigns a different value to `const result` than your client resulting in a hydration error.

To avoid that hydration error you can use a custom hook as described here:
[Next.js - new Date() constructor throwing console errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73005663/next-js-new-date-constructor-throwing-console-errors)